# change event is not passed on clicking checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

[image]
Below is the code snippet , I want any event(change in input element or click checkbox)  to call function updateUser. But updateUser is called only on enetering value inside input element but not on checking checkbox. Also, how to get the value from the checkbox?

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of record.roles;let i=index" (change)="updateUser($event)">

   <label for="name">AccountId</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.accountid" name="accountid"  required> 

  <label>IT Admin</label> 
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)] = "item.ITrole"  id="check2" [checked]="isChecked"  name="ITcheck" > 
  </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

I need to collect array of role values

```
record = {roles:[{accountid:null,role:[]}]};
```

Comment: `(ngModelChange)="updateUser()"`, on the input and the mat-checkbox. The value of the checkbox is in `this.item.ITrole`.

Comment: how do I access this.item.ITrole inside typescript

Comment: Try `(ngModelChange)="updateUser($event)"`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed the for loop. So `(ngModelChange)="updateUser(i)"`, and you access the checkbox value using `this.record.roles[i].ITrole`.

Comment: I am not able to click the checkboxes that are generated second in the row, I have updated the question with picture

Comment: I  am passing updateUser($event,i), you can see in the console, iam printing value of i. Somehow only first element is passed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all changes will be sync to the items object with ngModel you can use ngModelChange or change event because both input and mat-checkbox has chnge event and emit this event when value is changed.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of record.roles;let i=index" [ngStyle]="{margin:'1rem'}" >

   <label for="name">AccountId</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.accountid" 
            name="accountid"  required (change)="changeHandler(item)"> 
 <br>

  <label>IT Admin</label> 
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)] = "item.role.itAdmin" (change)="changeHandler(item)" > 
  </mat-checkbox>
  &nbsp;
    <label>User Portal</label> 
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)] = "item.role.userPortal"(change)="changeHandler(item)" > 
  </mat-checkbox>

</div>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftpvg3)

Comment: @karansys happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

You might have to put the change event on every editable field within the for loop like this

```
<div *ngFor="let item of record.roles">
  <label for="name">AccountId</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="item.accountid" name="accountid"  (ngModelChange)="updateUser(item) required> 

  <label>IT Admin</label> 
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="item.ITrole"  id="check2" [checked]="isChecked"  name="ITcheck" (ngModelChange)="updateUser(item)> 
  </mat-checkbox>
</div>
```